# Разложение изображения на кусочки 100x100 и сбор их обратно

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, изображения

Есть изображение размером 800x800. Его необходимо разложить на кусочки 100x100, а после некоторых манипуляций собрать эти кусочки в единое изображение.

Мой код:

представление изображения как массив и удаление 3 размерности

```
path_to_image = './la3.jpg'
image_array = plt.imread(path_to_image)
image_array = image_array[:, :, 0]
```

запись  в новый массив кусочков 100х100

```
main2_array = np.zeros(10000,)
for row in tqdm_notebook(range(0,8)):

    for col in range(0,8):
        main2_array = np.vstack((main2_array, image_array[0 + (100*row):100 + (100*row) ,0 + (100*col):100 + (100*col)].flatten()))

main2_array = np.delete(main2_array, main2_array[0] , axis=0  )
```

сбор кусочков 100x100 в изображение 800х800

```
main_array = np.zeros(100,)

for p in tqdm_notebook(range(0,100)):
    for i in range(0,64):
        main_array = np.vstack((main_array, main2_array[0 + (10000*i) + (100*p): 100 + (10000*i) + (100*p)]))

main_array = np.delete(main_array, main_array[0] , axis=0  )
```

После собора кусочков получаю такое изображение :

[image: изображение]

Исходное изображение:

[image: исходное]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431401/the-decomposition-and-collection-of-back-images-to-pieces-100x100-python вопрос решён на stack over flow

Comment: если думаете, что нашли решение, то опубликуйте как свой ответ, чтобы помочь людям с похожей проблемой (цель Stack Overflow). [Дублирование ответа на RU SO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2517/23044) и [Можно ли ответить на свой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Engineman, а в чем смысл данного кода? Вы пытаетесь написать методы для CNN (Convolutional Neural Network) с нуля? Ваш подход (вложенные циклы) будет работать на порядки медленнее готовых решений (tensorflow, keras, theano, caffee, etc.)

Comment: нет, цель понимание различных методов, сугубо в целях образования